# facebook login connect with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Say users can register normally on my website the good old username: email: and Password: fields.

But lets say a user decides to register on my site via facebook if i implement this. Now say when a user registers with facebook i ask them to make a username pass and submit there email with that information.

But when the user logins via facebook, how do i match it to the user in my mysql database or know who im logging in with?

Say my mysql contains user: pass: email: Do i need a new colum that somehow communicates these two logins? How would that work.

I was looking at [Facebook Login Methods here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/) Not sure which id need?

Answer (score 3):

The email address of the user is a key here. You can ask for the email address permission in addition to the other permission lists. And then you can compare with the one you have saved in your database. If the email address exists, then you log in the corresponding user, if not you save as a new user.

Comment: you can save that in your table. I guess the best approach is using the email address as a unique key here. Ofcourse in your sign up you make the email address as a required field. Whenever a registered user tries to login with facebook , you check if his email address matches with the one with facebook, then you log him in. If he's not registered to your website through your sign up form, then you save the email address with the other info you get from his facebook , then log him in.